# is there a way to customize keyboard shortcuts in LxTerminal?

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, lxterminal

Is there a way to change or add keyboard shortcuts within the LxTerminal application?  My specific desire is to change the bindings for previous and next tab so they match the shortcuts in my other environment, but I'm interested more generally if this is do-able across multiple applications, or if each application keeps shortcut key bindings in an app-specific location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you need an app-specific solution. For cross-application configurations [this page](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_lxde_keybinding.html) is helpful.

---

### The short answer:

- Unfortunately it is not possible to add new shortcuts.

### The long answer:

*lxterminal 0.2.0-1 (vivid)* has a property tab for shortcuts.

In previous versions, there is no such possibility. I also tried to use the configuration of the newer version with the older version. It does not work.

1. Start the terminal
2. Click *Edit* > *Preferences*
3. Select the *Shortcuts* tab
4. Make your changes

   [image]

Comment: This is very helpful, but my version of LxTerminal (installed with Lubuntu 14.04) does not have a "shortcuts" menu in the preferences section... I'll dig around but in the meantime could you tell me which version of LxTerminal you happen to be running?

Comment: @ljwobker I have updated my answer, bad news :\.

Comment: is there a way to install lxterminal 0.2.0-1 (vivid)?

Comment: @user4050 Please, don't ask new questions in a comment. [Ask here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)